# pfctl port forwarding in Mac osx?

Tags: mac, command-line, port-forwarding, iptables

```
-A PREROUTING -s 10.0.10.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
-A PREROUTING -s 10.0.10.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.10.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

The above code is a code Ive used to forward traffic in linux.

Now I need to do the same thing in Mac OSX. 10.8 if it matters.

So, here is the deal.

Before, I was using a proxy to connect to the linux machine and using that proxy I was able to monitor traffic using mitmproxy

Now, on the mac, Im using the built in internet sharing and want to use mitmproxy which only listens to stuff from port 8080.

```
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether ac:de:48:81:1d:4a 
    inet 192.168.2.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.2.255
    Configuration:
        priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0 maxage 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
    member: en0 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
             port 5 priority 0 path cost 0
```

The above is the "shared connection" that I need to forward I believe.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Assuming all your web traffic request will be from `192.168.2.0/24` and interface `bridge0`

Add following rules to **/etc/pf.conf**

```
rdr pass on bridge0 inet proto tcp from 192.168.2.0/24 to any port http -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
rdr pass on bridge0 inet proto tcp from 192.168.2.0/24 to any port https -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
```

**Quick Tips**

1. Test pf.conf for syntax error

   ```
   pfctl -v -n -f /etc/pf.conf
   ```
2. Apply/Reload the rules

   ```
   pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf
   ```

This is a [cheat-sheet](http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/a-cheat-sheet-for-using-pf-in-os-x-lion-and-up/) for OS X pfctl.

Comment: `pf` doesn't seem to be enabled by default, so you might have to add the `-e` flag: `pfctl -ef /etc/pf.conf`.

Comment: it says syntax error

Comment: @HiteshJoshi: I got the same problem. For me, moving the lines between the lines with "rdr-anchor" and "dummynet-anchor" fixed it.