# How to convert “ipfw” to “pfctl” commands to forward port 80 and 443 in OS X?

Tags: macos, port-forwarding, ipfw, pf

I found a way to forward ports 80 and 443 to other arbitrary ports (3000 and 3001 in my case) using ipfw. But ipfw is deprecated and replaced by pfctl. Here are my ipfw declarations:

```
sudo ipfw flush
sudo ipfw add 100 fwd 127.0.0.1,3000 tcp from any to me 443
sudo ipfw add 200 fwd 127.0.0.1,3001 tcp from any to me 80
sudo ipfw show
```

How can I do the same thing with pfctl please?

Comment: this is a duplicate

whatch for your answer here:
http://superuser.com/questions/473039/pfctl-port-forwarding-in-mac-osx

Comment: I am still using Mountain Lion on my laptop so I am not currently available to try this, but look around a bit on BSD-related forums for "pf port forwarding" and such if this does not help you! [Port forwarding in Mavericks (and above).](https://gist.github.com/kujohn/7209628)

Answer (score 1):

See [this AskDifferent answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/248064):

> To forward all port 80 traffic to port 8080, you can enter the following from the Terminal command line.
>
> ```
> echo "rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080" | sudo pfctl -ef -
> ```
>
> Taken from https://salferrarello.com/mac-pfctl-port-forwarding/

To forward ports 80 and 443 to ports 3000 and 3001, use these commands:

```
echo "rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 3000" | sudo pfctl -ef -
echo "rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 3001" | sudo pfctl -ef -
```