# OSX, Failed to listen on 0.0.0.0:80 (reason: Permission denied)

Tags: macos, networking, permissions, apache-http-server, php

I'm on OSX Mavericks. I installed PHP 5.5 from http://php-osx.liip.ch/. When I go to localhost in a browser I get a page that says, "It Works!" which is not a page I created so I am not sure where it is located. Is this from the PHP install or just Apache?

When I open my IDE (PHPStorm) and run the website, it works if I use a port like 8080. If I set the port to 80, it fails and the IDE says:

```
/usr/local/php5/bin/php -S 0.0.0.0:80 -t /mywebsitepath/ 

Failed to listen on 0.0.0.0:80 (reason: Permission denied)
```

When I searched for that specific error, all I found was help for [NGINX](https://superuser.com/questions/304206/how-do-i-start-nginx-on-port-80-at-os-x-login), but I am using Apache. What do I need to change to be able to run my code locally on port 80?

I want to do this so I can use localhost instead of localhost:8080.

Comment: Since you get a page from http://localhost, then means some software on your computer is already using port 80.  Two programs can't use the same port at the same time.

Comment: How can I see what is currently using it? I'm guessing it's something that happens at start-up.

Comment: For that, see [Who is listening on a given TCP port on Mac OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4421633/103167)

Comment: When I do `sudo lsof -i TCP:80 | grep LISTEN` I get no results.

Comment: you didn't turn off port number->name lookup, so it might be outputting `TCP:http` (I don't know about Mac `lsof`, but `netstat` on other OSes would).  Check the output of just `sudo lsof -i TCP` to see what format it is in.

Comment: Oh yea totally forgot, you could setuid on the php binary (or wrap it in a shell script). Its insecure, but as a dev environment it might just do

Comment: And IIRC OSX has launchd, its a bit like inetd, the internet super server. Its a binary that listens on all ports and spawns a corresponding process whenever a specific port is hit by a request

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ports below 1024 are privileged, and cannot be bound to by anyone other than root. Since you can't run your IDE as root, I would set up an Nginx proxy going from port 80 to port 8080, should be easy to do, there are many tutorials =D

Comment: Or an Apache proxy, if you are more familiar with that. Nginx rocks though. Oh and since you have OSX's Apache running on port 80, you'll have to stop it (or use *it* as a proxy)

Comment: He could probably run his IDE as root.. ''sudo open /Applications/PHPStorm'' - though I'm not sure if that IDE uses Workspaces in a way that he can point it at the project.. For dev/testing, running on a port above 1024 would seem like a bit less effort than an nginx reverse proxy, though they are fairly easy to establish.

Comment: If OSX's Apache is running on port 80 and I cannot use it from my IDE, is there any point in it running? Would it make sense to turn it off? Is that possible?

Comment: @Justin Unless you have something that is specifically required to be port 80 even in development, I would just use port 8080. It creates the least amount of headaches/work and security holes.

Comment: Thanks. While I was able to get Apache stopped so localhost address was freed up (no more "It works!" page), I still could not run my IDE on port 80 for the reason you describe in your answer. I'll just deal with the ugly URL for dev.